# Can a Web API controller GETter for query strings be generic?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

From Microsoft's [CRUD tutorial for their Web API:](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations)

> Finally, add a method to find products by category:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
{
    return repository.GetAll().Where(
            p => string.Equals(p.Category, category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

> If the request URI has a query string, Web API tries to match the query parameters to parameters on the controller method. Therefore, a URI of the form "api/products?category=category" will map to this method.

Is there any way to make this generic? As in GetProductsByWhateverIsInTheURI(string WhateverIsInTheURI) or "api/products?whatever=whatever"?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to make generic?  What is the purpose of `GetProductsByWhateverIsInTheURI`?

Comment: That particular method is mapped to only handle `?category=_category_` as a query string in the URI. This is mapped to `GetProductsByCategory(string category) because the name of the parameter matches the one queried for in the URI.
  
I was trying to figure out if there's a way to accept any sort of parameter in one generic method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd describe it as "generic", but you could just have a catch-all route that does away with parameter binding altogether. This would be a method that will "accept any sort of parameter in one method".

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    List<string> retval = new List<string>();

    var qryPairs = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
    foreach (var q in qryPairs)
    {
        retval.Add("Key: " + q.Key + " Value: " + q.Value);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed this a while ago... This is good, but I also need to match the key's value (based on the key's name) against the key with that value in the repository (Like the .Where() up there demonstrates). How could I modify this code to do that? Or am I just not seeing it.

Comment: There's a number of ways you could go about that. Something like this should get you started - http://pastebin.com/Y2qYiRnw